# Change Dir Where Chef Runs From

Tags: chef-infra

Chef is running from a user account (/home//.chef/cache/cookbooks/kelmar-server/resources)

This might be due to how each node is initially bootstrapped.
I need to update Chef's configuration to ensure that it runs a Chef owned directory /etc/chef or /opt/chef, or /home/chef.

FYI, chef cookbooks are stored in Git, Jenkins job runs these cookbooks from git onto the servers.

How do I change it?

Thanks,

Comment: Not getting a clear picture of the requirement. Do you mean `chef-client`? From which directory it runs should not matter. Why not just change to any of the directories you want and run it?

Comment: since the bootstrap it is running from /home/<user-account>. we need the chef to be running from /opt/chef or /etc/chef. because if the user is terminated and the user account is deleted, its going to be a problem.

Comment: @Santosh Use the [chef-client cookbook](https://supermarket.chef.io/cookbooks/chef-client#usage) with its `configure` recipe to reconfigure chef to use its usual cache path in /var/chef/